# macCatalyst: How to close the camera require For Mac version App?

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst

I am very new to Mac development, and My catalyst app was reject for 4 times now. The reason is that my App in iOS require camera to take photo, but it's useless on Mac.
However, I try to close the camera feature in 
         Project->Singing&Capebilities->App SandBox, 
         Project->inging&Capebilities->Hardened Runtime
         .entertament file
But they not work, the camera require is still show in System Settings' Privacy, If any one can help me to close this require on Mac?
Thanks for advance!

Comment: You can use the camera under Mac Catalyst. Why do you say it's useless?

Comment: Because my app is a to-do list app, user will use the back camera to take image for their files, but on Mac, the facetime camera seems to useless, show I plan to close the entrance of the "Take Photo " button. @rmaddy